# Is this the correct way to handle a response in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
var response = await App.PhrasespageCS.DisplayAlert("Reset score",
     "You have more than 50 points. Are you sure you want to reset it to 0?",
     "Yes", "No");

if (response == true)
{
    App.DB.ResetPointsForSelectedPhrase(App.cfs);
}
```

I am not clear on the use of await here and would appreciate advice.  Also could this be combined into one statement?

Comment: Await means here that you wait till the dialog has been created and answered. And yes think this the right way to handle a dialogresponse, although you don't have to write response == true you could simply just put response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Await means the app has created a dialog for you and is gonna wait till the answer comes in return. 
And that's the correct way to write it. Also if you wanna reduce the code you can put it as below,

```
if (await App.PhrasespageCS.DisplayAlert("Reset score", "You have more than 50 points.Are you sure you want to reset it to 0 ? ", "Yes", "No"))
            App.DB.ResetPointsForSelectedPhrase(App.cfs);
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [example](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups/) you should use await. Check [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayAlert/p/System.String/System.String/System.String/) also. The code for your purpose is given above in the answer.